# Unable to get Browsershot to work with query string parameters

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am running PHP Laravel 5.5.* with spatie/browsershot 3.24 and I am having an issue with pulling the HTML from a url that I generate from a route.

Code:

```
$url = route('pdfs.plans.results', [
                'lang' => $culture->code,
                'id' => $id,
                'user_id' => \Auth::user()->id,
                'pdf-token' => $token->token,
            ]);
```

And for now I'm just wanting to dd the raw html generated by this route:

```
dd(Browsershot::url($url)->bodyHtml());
```

However, this is failing and it appears to be due to the query parameters in the url string 
Example url: `http://localhost/pdf/plans/results/share?lang=en_US&id=17&user_id=8&pdf-token=PEvWJ7MB7sgQWM9AUfciceL4zNvZrLaSeemGf5J4kGzfOKvaMe8L0FTf32Da`

As soon as it hits the second parameter '`&id=17`' it breaks stating:

```
'id' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

which tells me that NodeJS is what's breaking, I'm guessing the ampersand is throwing it off and it's thinking that I'm passing another command to the console, but I don't know how else to get around this.

Is there a better way to pass the URL, or perhaps an alternative/better way to extract the rendered HTML from a Laravel blade (running VueJS) that I can then use for PDF generation or other business needs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe windows only related issue as I havent tried it on Linux yet, but I escaped the & and all now works fine.

```
$url = str_replace('&', '^&', $url)
```

Comment: This did it - sometimes it's the most simple answers that get the job done!